# Memory used on Ipod Classic that will not delete

Tags: itunes, ipod

I have an Ipod Classic 160G that I just bought. I uploaded my itunes library to it but for whatever reason it did not work. I then restored it to factory to delete these songs and retried. The new songs worked but now it shows that twice the memory is being used. I've tried restoring again and it still brings me back to 12G is being used but nothing is on it, so it says. How do I get these off/get back to the 160G?

Answer (score 1):

You can repair it with Disk Utility. First you have to open the iPod in iTunes and click "Enable disk use" and Sync. Then close iTunes and open Disk Utility, select the iPod and repair the disk. After repair, you can restore and disable the disk use.

Answer (score 0):

The hard disk might be damaged. There might be bad sectors that look, to a computer, as if they are used. I don't have a classic any more, but I think you can try reformatting it with Disk Utility. Use HFS+ non-journaled, and if it's not the right format, iTunes should be able to reformat it.